When God overshadowed Mary where did God get the material to make a baby and put in her womb?
Luke 1:35 And the angel answered and said unto her, The Holy Ghost shall come upon thee, and the power of the Highest shall overshadow thee: therefore also that holy thing which shall be born of thee shall be called the Son of God.

Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archived questions and answers as to how this plays out in practice.

The verse you quote says 'begotten of thee' (γεννωμενον εκ σου) not 'implanted into thee'. A human nature is involved with a human soul. Paul states 'come of woman' (γενομενον εκ γυναικος) Galatians 4:4. This is a human nature, come of woman.

@ Titus Tarnum - Excellent Question that gives an opportunity to clear up the mystery of Incarnation in a modern world of pharmaceutical and medical mentality! Hopefully many will be blessed, and eased in their minds.

So Nigel, you're saying that the zygote of Jesus came from Mary and not from God?

I am only prepared to quote scripture on such a solemn and divine matter.

I asked this because I've ran across people that think God used Mary's ovum to create the body of Jesus which sounds wrong to me.  Humanity didn't know about the female ovum until the 1800s and in Jesus day they believed that the male provided the complete person that would grow in the female womb. Then I thought what if God provided the complete zygote, and that zygote came from the very flesh of God making it sinless flesh.  That would give new meaning to the first Adam was of earth and the second was of heaven 1 Cor 15:47

The words 'the very flesh of God' make absolutely no sense at all. Jesus told us 'God is a Spirit'. Scripture tells us that Christ is 'God manifest in flesh' 1 Timothy 3:16 (TR/KJV).

Forgive me and please don't take offense; may I ask you what you believe about the zygote that was in Mary that grew into Christ's body; do you think God used one of Mary's ovum? Thank you!

Holy Spirit Overshadowing The Evangelist, Luke, used the right wording in repeating what the Angel revealed: The Holy Spirit shall come upon thee, and the power of the Highest shall overshadow thee. (Luke 1:35)
So to understand the supernatural Incarnation method, all one has to do is revert back to reading the first chapter of Genesis. It is there that we were told that God created (ex nihilo) the Heavens and the Earth, the land and the seas. (Genesis 1)
But when the Spirit hovered over the land and seas life sprang forth (animals and fishes)! The hovering, or as the angel said to Mary, overshadowing, produced Living Beings both in the Old Testament, and here in the New Testament.
There was no "conception", but a supernatural act of God: an incarnation...by the Holy Spirit's power.

a lot of atheists claim Yahweh had intercourse with Mary, coming upon her, and even though he is spirit, he covered her and impregnated her. They also claim Mary was a teenager, The usual age they choose is 15 or 16, rarely some say 12, There is absolutely no proof for this, just like there is no proof Mary Magdelene was a prostitute, scripturally speaking. Some atheists claim the Holy Spirit raped Mary because she never gave her consent. So they claim.

@ Saber Truth Tiger - Tis indeed a bone of contention for such a Tiger as yourself, for your confronting atheists---and seekers. Be it unto me, as you say. does not sound like "rape."  Spirit is not flesh. There was a lot of Medieval myths about connubial affairs between spirits and women...but just myths! Keep studying the Bible; it's great for the soul!

+1. Good answer!

@Dottard     'no conception'. Downvoted -1. Here is expressed the creation of a human by supernatural means. Rather than the conception (not involving male and female contributions but a conception which conjoins that which is Divine to that which is human) which scripture reveals.

@NigelJ - first, this is not my answer but Ray Grant's.  Second, I am always confused by your comments on this subject - previously you suggested that Jesus was never an embryo nor a fetus - but now you object to "no conception".  I am still flummoxed by your theology here.

@Dottard I have never commented on the matter of either embryo or fetus. I think you are mistaken. But without a conception there is no conjoining of Divine nature and human nature - only a supernatural creation, resulting in a supernatural human. (But not 'God manifest in flesh'.) Which was the point of my comment. Yes, indeed, it is not your answer but I was contrasting my downvote against your own upvote, was all.

@NigelJ - I refer to this conversation which still confuses me.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121296/discussion-between-dottard-and-nigel-j

@Dottard I refer you to the full text of my book The Son of Man wherein the subject is laid out in detail. The PDF file of the book is on my website and may be downloaded free of charge and without registration.

Regarding Mary bearing Jesus, there are a lot of possibilities and even more speculation, not to mention the usual vacuous assertions from non-believers.
Certainly, God could have formed Jesus from the dust of the earth as he did with Adam. God could have had Mary discover baby Jesus in a basket floating in the Jordan River. God could have created a zygote ex nihilo in Mary’s body, or God could have fused two haploid egg cells from Mary’s ovaries and truncated and hacked one of Mary's X chromosomes into a suitable Y chromosome (God doesn’t need CRISPR).
God likely chose for Mary to bear Jesus parthenogetically for the following reasons:

God planned to utterly destroy Satan for murdering the humanity that God lovingly created in his own image.
God planned to accomplish the destruction of the massively powerful Satan by means of the weak and mortal humanity that Satan plotted to destroy.
God promised Eve the honor of knowing that her seed (an odd expression meaning NOT Adam’s seed) would crush the serpent’s head at the cost of his heel being wounded. And that there would be hostility between her seed and Satan’s seed. This is “the desire of women” (in the literal Hebrew) alluded to in Daniel 11:37.
Mary would bear Jesus without the participation of Joseph as the will of man. Just as Eve was formed from Adam, God formed Jesus from Mary. Mary’s genetic line by means of her ovaries traced back to King David as was prophesied. Thus, Jesus was the “Son of David” in fulfillment of the prophecy of 2 Samuel 7:12-16. Jesus was also the “Son of Man” as prophesied in Daniel 7:13.
The curse of sin of the descendants of Adam and Eve could be avoided by an intervention by God in creating a new, “second Adam” from the woman. Satan would then have to try to also corrupt the second Adam, which he failed to do.
Jesus then kept all 613 laws of Torah perfectly to God’s satisfaction under the ever watchful and hypercritical eyes of the Judaean religious leadership. He was sacrificed as a perfect Passover lamb to fulfill Torah so all of his authentic disciples could instead be “born again,” passing from spiritual death into life, constantly being made ritually clean by the Father (i.e. cleansed) and empowered to bear the fruit of the Spirit as described in John 15, and could be resurrected to eternal life just as Jesus was.


So you believe that God manipulated an egg of Mary's and God didn't add anything to it? If God had used any flesh that was passed down through Adam wouldn't it be tainted with original sin? Thank you!

@Titus Tarnum, The comments here are not for the purpose of argument. So, please allow me to leave you with this question to think about. When you read Matthew 5:27-28, what do the words of Jesus tell you about the origin of sin? Or similarly in the Tanakh, why is God fed up in Isaiah 1:11-20?
